Wick rotation in multiple dimensions (and thus a question about multivariate complex analysis)
In physics, one often encounters this problem:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \frac{1}{x^2-E^2+i\epsilon}$$
Now we know that an integral over a closed curve $\gamma$ in the complex plane of a holomorphic function on $\gamma\subset U$ is 0, so we can wick rotate $x$ from the real line to the imaginary line. (Avoiding the poles)
A related question is how to do this if I had more than one variable:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} dx dy \frac{1}{x^2+y^2-E^2+i\epsilon}$$
(one might need to understand the domain here as integration over a disc of radius $R$ tending to infinity.)
In the $\mathbb{C}^2 \simeq \mathbb{R}^4$ space, the singularities make up a 3 dimensional submanifold. (Or if we had something like a $\sqrt{.}$ it would even be a 4d subspace).
Is there a theorem that states that if one integrates over a (possibly compact and then taking some kind of radius to infinity) hypersurface without any singularities inside, that one knows this must be 0? If so, then could I Wick rotate in every variable separately here?
I'm also not sure if this interpretation of a kind of "Cauchy principal value" by taking the domain of integration to infinity is even allowed here.
(P.s. the other SE questions about this topic kind of tell you that a lot of prerequisites are needed, most of which I do not have. So it would be nice if the answer could be kept at a "basic" level)
ADDED: As a sanity check here, the result should coincide with doing polar coordinates, where the angle goes over $[0,\pi[$ and $r\in ]-\infty, \infty[$ and then wick rotating in the radial coordinate. But I guess this is also just my intuition speaking that these two should be the same.
